# How do I fix this graph so that it hits the x-axis at the right spot like in desmos?

Tags: pgfplots

This is what I currently have:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\hspace*{\fill}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[width=4in,axis equal image,
          xmax=3,ymax=1.5,
          axis lines=middle,
          enlargelimits,
          axis line style={shorten >=-0.25cm,shorten <=-0.25cm,latex-latex},
          ticklabel style={fill=white},
          extra x ticks={0},
          xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$,
          clip=false,
          trig format=rad
]

\addplot[domain=0:4,samples=200] {(3*(2*x-sin((2*x)))/(8*pi(1-cos(x))-sin(x))} node[fill=white, right]{$y=\frac{3(2x-\sin{2x})}{8\pi(1-\cos{x})}-\sin{x}$};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

This is what it should look like:

[image]

It's close but I feel like something little is off, it doesn't hit the x-axis where it should.

Answer (score 2):

The main issue lies with your function definition; there are some grouping/parentheses issues.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[width=4in,axis equal image,
    xmax=3,ymax=1.5,
    axis lines=middle,
    enlargelimits,
    axis line style={shorten >=-0.25cm,shorten <=-0.25cm,latex-latex},
    ticklabel style={fill=white},
    extra x ticks={0},
    xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$,
    clip=false,
    trig format=rad
  ]

  \addplot[domain=0:4,samples=200] {
    3*(2*x - sin(2*x)) / (8*pi*(1 - cos(x))) - sin(x)} node[fill=white, right]
    {$y = \frac{3 (2 x - \sin{2 x})}{8 \pi (1 - \cos{x})} - \sin{x}$};

  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

This is what it looks like over a larger domain (`0:5.5`):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx,tikz,pgfplots}
\begin{document}

\hspace*{\fill}
\begin{tikzpicture}[trig format=rad]
    \begin{axis}[width=4in,axis equal image,
        xmax=6,ymax=3,
        axis lines=middle,
        enlargelimits,
        axis line style={shorten >=-0.25cm,shorten <=-0.25cm,-latex},
        ticklabel style={fill=white},
        extra x ticks={0},
        xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$,
        clip=false,
        ]
        
        \addplot[domain=0:6,samples=200] {(3*(2*x-sin(deg(2*x)))/(8*pi(1-cos(x))-sin(x)} node[right]{$y=\frac{3}{8\pi}\frac{2x-\sin 2x}{1-\cos x}$};
        
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
    
\end{document}
```

[image]